# Multiple script errors - filter_glob, filepath do_colormanage, createGeom, SVGParseCoord, TypeError:float, location

Tags: error

I am new to Blender and made, what I think, is a very simple svg, but when I try to import it into the program I get the following error messages;

```
self.as_keywords(=ignore=(filter_glob))) line 61
load_svg(filepath do_colormanage) line 1904
load_svg loader.createGeom(False) line 1895
createGeom self.doCreateGeom(instancing) line 1115
_doCreateGeom geom.createGeom(instancing) line 1167
_doCreateGeom document_height = SVGParseCoord(raw_height 1.0)
SVGParseCoord val = float(token) line 160
TypeError:float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I haven't installed any addons or plugins.
All the lines are the same color and line width and the paths are not filled

here you can find my svg and the error messages

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m66TtosNf8MqEkm0NVQyYOFZreOzAAad

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m66TtosNf8MqEkm0NVQyYOFZreOzAAad?usp=sharing0

Comment: Copy paste your objects into a new clean SVG file, then import again